# Stereoscopic Vision: Calculating Length of Triangle Line

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the length of the blue line $z$ in the following image.  If angle $d_t$, $d_r$ and the red line $p$ forming the base of the triangle are known.  How can I calculate the length of the blue line $z$?

I suspect some trigonometry is involved.

[image: A]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the internal angles in the dotted triangle, then from these and the angles $d_t,d_r$ you know the internal angles of the red triangle. Then the sine rule will tell you the other sides.

Comment: What theorem is applied such that if internal angles of the dotted triangle are known and $d_t$, $d_r$, the internal angles of the red triangle can be calculated?  When you state internal angles of the red triangle do you mean the triangle that includes the side $p$?  In regards to the sine rule, I'm assuming you mean applying it to either triangle in which $p/2$?

Comment: The sine rule also requires 6/7 measurements to solve for $z$, sides $a$, $b$, $z$ and angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and circumcircle radius $R$.  I'm a little confused how I would calculate the circumcircle radius $R$ for the red triangle.  Is there a way to calculate this based on the known parameters?